# Why a git merge is happening?

Tags: git, github

When push a commit from my local machine and I do a git pull on a server, an editor is opened and it asks for a `git commit` text and a new `git commit` with merge text is created with another user as author. So git log will be (bbbbbb is my actual commit):

```
commit cccccc............
Merge: aaaaaa bbbbbb
Author: User 2

    Merge branch 'master' of repo1

commit bbbbbb.................
Author: My username

    My changes

commit aaaaa.................
```

Why is that? and how change it in a way that there is no need for this merge step on the server. My guess: on that server, "User 1" can just `git push` directly to repository manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git fetch` to retrieve the latest revisions. That's the equivalent to pulling in Mercurial. `git pull` combines fetch **and** merge.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do a rebase instead of a merge. Understand what rebase is, and then proceed - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/

Try doing a `git pull --rebase` instead of just a `git pull`.